# Am I using the useEffect hook correctly to try and fetch data?

Tags: reactjs

I am having some issues with my React code when trying to use the useEffect hook to fetch data from an API.

This is my boiled down code:

```
const App = () => {

    const [ data, setData ] = useState([]);
    const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        
        const loadData = async () => {

            try {
                setLoading(true);
                const response = await fetch(`htts://localhost/api/`);
                const json = await response.json();
                console.log(json);
                setData(json);
                setLoading(false);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("error: " + error);
            }
        }

        loadData();

    }, []);
}
```

I am running into issues that when I render the html it's giving me errors that I am unable to map to some of the `data` that I am setting from my API.

I was thinking that setting the `data` variable would give me the ability to spit out data in the template and the various object key names like:

```
{
     data.keyname.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                    <option key={ index }
                            value={ item.displayName }
                    >
                    { item.displayName }
                    </option>
            );
    })
}
```

Am I overlooking something here? It appears that my data isn't loading so the render code can't loop through any of the data it needs to in order to render the app.

Comment: Could you show us what `console.log(json);` prints?

Comment: The code looks fine. The problem is probably at the data you are fetching (either it is inconsistent or just has different fields than the ones you are referncing)

Comment: You can guard it via optional chaining data?.keymap?.map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your try to map anything in return of your component, it has to be initialized as an array. It doesn't matter if its empty, but always has to be an array.

So i suggest you initialize your "data" like this:

```
    const [ data, setData ] = useState({anyKeyName:[]});
```

Answer (score 0):

What is `data.keyname`?  `data` starts out as an array:

```
const [ data, setData ] = useState([]);
```

And an array has no `keyname` property.  So this will fail with an error saying you can't invoke `.map` on `undefined`:

```
data.keyname.map((item, index) => {
```

If what you're getting back from the server is expected to be an *object* which has an array *property* called `keyname`, initialize your default object to match that:

```
const [ data, setData ] = useState({ keyname: [] });
```

Basically it sounds like your `useEffect` logic is working (assuming the response is what you expect it to be), but you simply have a mis-match between your initial state and what you expect that state to be when rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `Optional chaining(?)` is the quick and solid solution for this.

```
{
     data?.keyname?.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                    <option key={ index }
                            value={ item.displayName }
                    >
                    { item.displayName }
                    </option>
            );
    })
}
```

Learn more about [Optional_chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Answer (score 0):

Initializing data as an empty array without handling the other fetching states is opening your app up to UI bugs and hard errors - which all can be avoided if you handle all of the data fetching states.

There are at least 4 states that are traditionally handled when fetching data -

- Data not fetched (data null)
- Fetching (loading)
- Error fetching (error)
- Data Fetched (data)

See below for an example on how to handle all 4 states without breaking the app's UI if something goes wrong or no data is returned.

```js
const App = () => {

    const [ data, setData ] = useState(null);
    const [ error, setError ] = useState(false);
    const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {        
     const loadData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
       const response = await fetch(`htts://localhost/api/`);
       // response is not asynchronous - don't await.
       setData(response.json());
      } catch (error) {
       console.error("error: ", error); // make sure you remove this on build - you can also use common instead of concatenation 
       setError(true)
      } finally {
       setLoading(false); // move loading state so it always exits the loading state on error or success - currently if yours has an error your app will be stuck in loading state.
     }
    }
    loadData();
   }, []);

   if( loading ) return <>Loading component</>;
   if( error ) return <>Error component </>;
   // check if data was returned and verify it's not just an empty array
   if (!data || !data.keyname.length) return <>No data found component </>;

   return (
    <>
     {data.keyname.map(({ displayName, id }) => (
       <option 
        key={ id } // should use something unique to this set of elements (not index) like item.id - if the id is auto incremented then prefix it with something unique for this component like `keynames-${id}`
        value={ displayName }
        >
         { displayName }
        </option>
      )}
    </>
   )
}
```